# Parsing file names with javascript

Tags: javascript

I have file names like the following:

SEM_VSE_SKINSHARPS_555001881_181002_1559_37072093.DAT
SEM_VSE_SECURITY_555001881_181002_1559_37072093.DAT
SEM_VSE_MEDICALCONDEMERGENCIES_555001881_181002_1559_37072093.DAT
SEM_REASONS_555001881_181002_1414_37072093.DAT
SEM_PSE_NPI_SECURITY_555001881_181002_1412_37072093.DAT

and I need to strip the numbers from the end. This will happen daily and and the numbers will change. I HAVE to do it in javascript. The problem is, I know really nothing about javascript. I've looked at both split and slice and I'm not sure either will work. These files come from a government entity which means the file name will probably not be consistent.

expected output:

SEM_VSE_SKINSHARPS

SEM_VSE_SECURITY

SEM_VSE_MEDICALCONDEMERGENCIES

SEM_REASONS

SEM_PSE_NPI_SECURITY

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe you should edit your post and include the expected output of those files in your example list.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a good use case for regular expressions. For example,

```
var oldFileName = 'SEM_VSE_SKINSHARPS_555001881_181002_1559_37072093.DAT',
    newFileName;
newFileName = oldFileName.replace(/[_0-9]+(?=.DAT$)/, ''); // SEM_VSE_SKINSHARPS.DAT
```

This says to replace as many characters as it can in the set `-` and `0-9`, with the requirement that the replaced portion must be followed by `.DAT` and the end of the string.

If you want to strip the `.DAT`, as well, use `/[_0-9]+.DAT$/` as the regular expression instead of the one above.

Comment: All 3 suggestions worked. This one is probably going to work best for my needs. I envy you folks that an read regex. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

If all the files end in `.XYZ` and follow the given pattern, this might also work:

```
var filename = "SEM_VSE_SKINSHARPS_555001881_181002_1559_37072093.DAT"
filename.slice(0,-4).split("_").filter(x => !+x).join("_")
```

results in:

```
"SEM_VSE_SKINSHARPS"
```

This is how it works:

1. drop the last 4 chars (.DAT)
2. split by `_`
3. filter out the numbers
4. join what is remaining with another `_`

You can also create a function out of this solution (or the other ones) and use it to process all the files provided they are in an array:

```
var fileTrimmer = filename => filename.slice(0,-4).split("_").filter(x => !+x).join("_")
var result = array_of_filenames.map(fileTrimmer)
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is a solution that assumes you have your file name strings stored in an array. The code below simply creates a new array of properly formatted file names by utilizing `Array.prototype.map` on the original array - the `map` callback function first grabs the extension part of the string to tack on the file name later. Next, the function breaks the `fileName` string into an array delimited on the `_` character. Finally, the `filter` function returns `true` if it does not find a number within the `fileName` string - returning `true` means that the element will be part of the new array. Otherwise, `filter` will return false and will not include the portion of the string that contains a number.

```js
var fileNames = ['SEM_VSE_SKINSHARPS_555001881_181002_1559_37072093.DAT', 'SEM_VSE_SECURITY_555001881_181002_1559_37072093.DAT', 'SEM_VSE_MEDICALCONDEMERGENCIES_555001881_181002_1559_37072093.DAT', 'SEM_REASONS_555001881_181002_1414_37072093.DAT', 'SEM_PSE_NPI_SECURITY_555001881_181002_1412_37072093.DAT'];

var formattedFileNames = fileNames.map(fileName => {
  var ext = fileName.substring(fileName.indexOf('.'), fileName.length);
  var parts = fileName.split('_');
  return parts.filter(part => !part.match(/[0-9]/g)).join('_') + ext;
});

console.log(formattedFileNames);
```